# NEXT JS ---- npm ERR! code ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, npm, next.js

```
npm ERR! code ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT
npm ERR! network Socket timeout
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Creative Impex Inter\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-10-17T17_56_18_211Z-debug-0.log
```

I am getting this error when installing firebase. I then tried to create a new next js project and now it is not even installing it.

Answer (score 0):

This error usually comes because of network instability, you can use yarn.

```
npm i -g yarn
```

Install it globally and then try to setup your project, and you can install dependencies with `yarn add` instead of `npm install`